# How do I change tkinter default title in OS bar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a python app using Tkinter and I cannot find a way to change the default title `Tk` in OS top bar (Gnome top bar and dock too).
I can set the main window title but it does not change the string in the top bar where it stays `Tk`. Honestly I am surprised I cannot find anyone asking this same question.

I am developing on Ubuntu 18.04 using Python 3.6

This is a sample code to replicate the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainWindow = tk.Tk()
    mainWindow.title("TEST")
    mainWindow.geometry("1024x600")
    mainWindow.mainloop()
```

I would expect to read the string `TEST` in the main window frame title, in the OS top bar and in the OS application dock, but I get it only in the windows frame title. The rest display `Tk`

Comment: How interesting, it works fine for Windows...maybe you need to submit a ticket to `tkinter` developers or something

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: @Mike-SMT are you on Ubuntu?

Comment: No I am not currently on a linux distro. I will have to wait till I get home to test it. Your code is correct and should work so if it is not there there is likely a known bug as the title very often something people change and I imaging something like this problem is already documented.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot

Answer (score 4):

Use **className**

```py
mainWindow = tk.Tk(className='Ghanshyam')
```

According to python [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter.Tk) on tkinter:

> The Tk class is instantiated without arguments. This creates a toplevel widget of Tk which usually is the main window of an application. Each instance has its own associated Tcl interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The top bar title in Ubuntu is not set by the application running, it is set by the desktop entry for the app. I'm not sure why it works the way it does when there is no desktop entry present, but you can create a file like this and import it into Ubuntu for it to work properly.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/path/to/icon/icon.png
Name=TITLE (this is what handles the top bar title)
Exec=/path/to/file/executable
Categories=Utility;
```

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690104/how-to-change-name-in-top-bar-for-an-application-in-gnome) on AskUbuntu.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/` and now I can run the app also from the ubuntu dash launcher, but the title is still fixed to Tk. I will investigate more this approach, maybe there is something else to do.

Comment: same issue here. root.title("..") + desktop file "Name" properties all set to nice name but the menu bar keeps displaying "Tk" - really strange. I am on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @samba2 Did u found a solution?