# Name in .desktop file not working in tkinter - python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tkinter, desktop

I made a python application in **tkinter**. Then I made **Debian** installer and installed it on PC. Now I want my Application name which is ***Ghanshyam*** in TopBar instead of **Tk**. This is how it looks in TopBar right now

[image]

**I want a custom name in TopBar. (Not Tk)**

Suppose my App Name is *Firefox Web Browser*. I want something like this:

[image]

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56222843/11605100) answer, I have to add a line in desktop entry for the app

```
Name=TITLE
```

which I have already done.

**ghanshyam.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Ghanshyam
Comment=Comment in ghanshyam.desktop file
Exec=/usr/bin/ghanshyam/main
Icon=/usr/share/icons/ghanshyam/icon.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Above shown is my desktop file. You can see I have already written **Name** in my desktop entry. Yet my app is showing **Tk** instead of **Ghanshyam**. How can I solve this?

Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance :)

---

Details:

**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04 | **Python**: 3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have looked into docs. Well, it will be useful to someone in future.

Use **className**

```py
root = Tk(className='Ghanshyam')
```

According to python [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter.Tk) on tkinter:

> The Tk class is instantiated without arguments. This creates a toplevel widget of Tk which usually is the main window of an application. Each instance has its own associated Tcl interpreter.